# Getting data out of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

below is array info, I just need to echo out what is for Array. So you will see that in data there is Example 1 and Example 3, Just need to echo that out.

This: $user->getFieldValue('AUTOCOMPLETE'); when I print_r, is the results below.

```
SocialFieldValue Object
(
    [unique_key] => AUTOCOMPLETE
    [element] => autocomplete
    [field_id] => 161
    [uid] => 84
    [type] => user
    [value] => Array
        (
            [Example 1] => Example 1
            [Example 3] => Example 3
        )

    [raw] => ["Example 1","Example 3"]
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Example 1
            [1] => Example 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Its actually an object that contains properties some of which are arrays

Comment: `echo $objectname->value['Example 1'];`

Comment: If have tried at least once, you would have got your answer, you would.  Yes, hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test this code?

```
$user->getFieldValue('AUTOCOMPLETE')->value['Example 1'];
```

Comment: thank you. I actually used $user->getFieldValue('AUTOCOMPLETE')->data['0'], because multiple values can be added to the section that creates the above data. So calling out data['0'], next would be data['1'] and so forth. That way I can get whatever is in the values.

Comment: So to get it dynamiclly, I did this
                    `foreach ($user->getFieldValue('AUTOCOMPLETE')->data as $key) {
                        echo $key . "<br>";
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple you need to access prop using ->

```
$autoComplete = $user->getFieldValue('AUTOCOMPLETE');
$data = $autoComplete->data;
```

Now you can access its items with.

```
echo $data[0] // prints Example 1
```